# GDI+ GetHBITMAP memory error?

Tags: c++, windows, gdi+

So I was trying to learn some GDI basics and my code breaks when I try to get the HBITMAP for a png image I want to display...

```
HBITMAP SplashScreen::LoadPng(WCHAR* path)
{
  HBITMAP bmp;
  fstream f;
  f.open(path);
  if(!f.good())
  {
    throw std::exception("Can't find/read file.");
  }
  f.close();

  Gdiplus::Bitmap* img = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromFile(path, FALSE); 
  Gdiplus::Color bg(0,0,0,0); 
  img->GetHBITMAP(bg, &bmp);     // <--- Breaks here! Memory access exception!

  return bmp;
}
```

The code is already so simple, I can't think of anything wrong with it, except maybe I just didn't set something up beforehand??

Thoughts?

Comment: Your code is missing the required error checking.  If the FromFile() method fails, *img* will be null.  Kaboom.

Comment: What causes it to fail... besides wrong path. I know it's got that right.

Comment: @HansPassant, I pulled up the documentation and it doesn't specify *what* it does when it fails. Are you sure it's null?

Comment: Most probably Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromFile fails and so `img` is null

Comment: Yes, img is null, but why? The path is correct. Also the img is a png from Photoshop.

Comment: Many reasons why FromFile can fail, most obvious - wrong or unsupported file format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your problem is, though, I do note that you've got a memory leak.
`img` is never `delete`d - you should call `delete img;` after the call to GetHBITMAP

I use the following (less thorough code) in quick test projects.

```
// BMP, GIF, JPEG, PNG, TIFF, Exif, WMF, and EMF
HBITMAP mLoadImg(WCHAR *szFilename)
{
   HBITMAP result=NULL;

   Gdiplus::Bitmap* bitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(szFilename,false);
   bitmap->GetHBITMAP(0, &result);
   delete bitmap;
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured there was probably a memory leak too lol. I wasn't sure if the HBITMAP would still be valid if I deleted the bitmap before returning. I guess the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't initialize GDI correctly. After fixing my init code, it works fine. That was annoying. Now I know.